# Seeking hint for Lebesgue measure question

Tags: measure-theory

For any measurable function $f$ on a measure space $(E,\mathcal{E},\mu)$ And $0\le f \le b$ for some $b\in (0,\infty)$ constant, then 
$$\mu(f) = \inf \{\mu(g): g\ge f\, \text{and}\, g \text{ simple}\}$$

I consider two cases where $\mu(E)<\infty$. This is easy, the statement holds by Lebesgue dominated convergent theorem. But I am not sure how should I approach when $\mu(E) = \infty$...

Comment: How do you define$ \mu (f)$? Do you mean the Lebesgue integral of f?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\mu(E) = \infty$ it's false in general.  Take your measure space to be $[0,\infty)$ with Lebesgue measure $\mu$.  Let $f(x) = e^{-x}$; we have $0 \le f \le 1$ and $\mu(f) = 1$.  However, $f > 0$ everywhere.  If $g \ge f$ is a simple function, then $g$ has only finitely many values in its range, and they all must be strictly positive.  Let $c>0$ be the smallest of them.  That means $g \ge c$ everywhere and hence $\mu(g) \ge c \mu([0, \infty)) = \infty$.  So the inf on the right side of your claimed equation is infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: apply the definition of the integral (as the supremum over integrals of test functions that do not exceed $f$) for the positive function $b-f$.